# Changing the CommandTimeout in SQL Management studio

Tags: sql, ssms, timeoutexception

How can I change the CommandTimeout in SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Changing Command Execute Timeout in **Management Studio**:

Click on Tools -> Options

Select **Query Execution** from tree on left side and enter command timeout in "*Execute Timeout*" control.

Changing Command Timeout in **Server**:

In the object browser tree right click on the server which give you timeout and select "*Properties*" from context menu.

Now in "*Server Properties -.....*" dialog click on "**Connections**" page in "Select a Page" list (on left side). On the right side you will get property

```
Remote query timeout (in seconds, 0 = no timeout):
[up/down control]
```

you can set the value in up/down control.

Comment: Note that the second part (remote query timeout) only affects outgoing connection initiated by the Database Engine. Had me confused a first. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/ms189040.aspx

Answer (score 156):

If you are getting a timeout while on the table designer, change the "Transaction time-out after" value under Tools --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers

This will get rid of this message: **"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."**

[image]

Comment: This is an important addition to two suggestions in the accepted answer - it's a third setting that, in my case at least, was the actual source of the problem.  Make sure to check all three places!

Comment: You should actually uncheck the **Override connection string time-out value for table design updates** option. [This will cause it to revert to using the *Query Timeout* option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915849). The eliminates the problem of bumping up the timeout seconds to (a maximum of `65,535`), and having your table changes time-out after 18 hours. (Which do happen; which is how i discovered *"broken by default"*)

Comment: helped me to stop **"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."**

Comment: @IanBoyd still get the same message.

Comment: If you are resizing a column and get the timeout expired error, this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, what a relief. Now I can modify column sizes without first deleting all rows in my table

Answer (score 9):

Right click in the query pane, select `Query Options...` and in the Execution->General section (the default when you first open it) there is an `Execution time-out` setting.

Comment: Thank you! SSMS 18 cached this settings for file, and even restart doesn't help when change Tools -> Options.

Answer (score 0):

While on the table designer, you get error : **"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."**

Remove check box under : Tools --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers --> Override connection string time-out value for table designer updates

[image]

Then timeout, refers to "connection string execution timeout"

So if you uncheck it, you have to close **ssms** and launch it again

When reopening, at "connect to server" dialouge, before connecting, press options button, go to "connection properties" tab,
and make sure "execution time-out" value set to zero (it means unlimited)

[image]