# Options to mitigate SQL Server timeout on giant batch insert

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a script that works swimmingly in my dev environment:

```
INSERT INTO [Voyage] ([StartDate], [EndDate] ...)
SELECT ([StartDate], [EndDate] ...) FROM [LEG]
WHERE [STARDATE] IS NOT NULL
AND [ENDDATE] IS NOT NULL
```

All well and good, until this script is run in production. I'm told we have a billion `Leg` records, and the server is timing out because of it.

Anyone have a strategy to employ for a scenario like this?

Comment: Any chance of breaking up the batch?  For example run a few months at a time.  With a billion records, I'm surprised your DBA's haven't mentioned anything about log growth and blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the script in SQL Management Studio? You should be able to just let it run. A different query client could have a timeout issue. See this answer to verify the timeout is set to 0 (no timeout):

[Changing the CommandTimeout in SQL Management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137190/changing-the-commandtimeout-in-sql-management-studio)