# Can't get to next stage of Kentico application configuration

Tags: sql-server, kentico, kentico-mvc

I'm trying to get my web application up and running. It uses Kentico. I connected to the admin page which is taking me through the initial database ans site setup. It ran through "Creating database objects". I can see the tables are now in the database. The "Next" button hasn't become active.

This error is in the Creating database objects log:

```
at CMS.DataEngine.SqlInstallationHelper.ImportDefaultData(IDataConnection connection, String dataFolder, LogMessage log, String defaultErrorMessage)
at CMS.DataProviderSQL.DataConnection.BulkInsert(DataTable sourceData, String targetTable, BulkInsertSettings insertSettings)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.HandleError(String queryText, Exception ex)

The statement has been terminated.
Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Caused exception:

BulkInsert to table 'BadWords_Word'
Query:

[DataConnection.HandleError]:
ERROR:  An error occurred:
data\badwords_word
objects/proc_personas_reevaluateallcontacts
...
objects/cms_resource
```

How  can I get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the timeout for your connection string in your web.config file to something like 600 then try again.

Comment: I tried that but still get the issue. I noticed that when I set the timeout to 600 I get the message long before that time is up.

Comment: @runnerpaul try setting the execution timeout then:  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />  or you can look here to change it on the server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137190/changing-the-commandtimeout-in-sql-management-studio

Comment: I also beefed up cpu and ram in my computer as it was struggling.